# How to import string from a .txt file C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a password generator, that uses elements of an array to generate a word-based password.

I currently am working with four arrays, with a lot of elements, and I have to hardcode them individually. I want to automate that process, because writing in a .txt file is both easier and cleaner than writing it on the code itself, and as I plan on distributing this program to my friends, I want to be able to make libraries for the arrays.

Simply put, the .txt file will have four lines, each for one of the arrays.

All I need to know currently is how to import each the lines of the text as a single string, which will be individually formatted into the arrays.

So, for example, the .txt file would have this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
d,e,f,g,h,i,j
g,h,i,j,k,l,m
j,k,l,m,n,o,p
```

And after the "fetching", four different strings would contain each of the lines:

```
string a = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
string b = "d,e,f,g,h,i,j"
string c = "g,h,i,j,k,l,m"
string d = "j,k,l,m,n,o,p"
```

I will then process it by this, for each string, to break them down into elements.

```
String pattern = @"\-";
String[] elements = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(passKey, pattern);
```

Comment: _All I need to know currently is how to import each the lines of the text as a single string_ - like `var lines = File.RealAllLines(path)`? That reads them as an array, which you can then separate into separate strings if you want, but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Bit confused as well about your Regex, as that won't match your strings? You're looking for `-` which they don't contain? If you want to split them by a character, why not use `var elements = a.Split(',');`?

Comment: Load all text from the file using *System.IO.File.ReadAllText* (Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file) Then split the loaded text by \n loadedText.Split('\n') for example.

Comment: Oh yeah, that Regex is from the actual code, while the strings are an example string,  because putting the actual word strings would be highly impractical, as they are 50 words long. @stuartd

Comment: @Younes Funnily enough, I came across that exact article when searching for another way of doing it... I'm fairly new to this, and don't really have that much time to read all the documentation, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt");
```

To put them in an array specifically, use:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt").ToArray();
```

Comment: There's no point using `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` if you're going to put the results into an array - as the docs say _The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, **when you are working with very large files**, ReadLines can be more efficient._

Comment: Thanks for helping! This actually managed to read it, and putting it all already into an array made it way easier for me, as I still have to further decompose each array into another, to via the Regex. This is probably the most roundabout way of actually doing it, but if it works...